# Why does ajax `data` cause this code to break?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm new to JavaScript but I've written some code that as far as I can see is formatted correctly however when I add the `data` elements in it breaks the code but I cannot see why as according to the jQuery documentation, I am using `.val()` correctly etc.

```
<script>
$( "#button1" ).click(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
                "data": [
                    "date1": $( "#inputDate1" ).val(),
                    "date2": $( "#inputDate2" ).val(),
                ],
                "url": "/server_processing/database.php",
                "type": "POST"
                },
        "serverSide": true
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a HTML or Fiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array literal `[]` contains a comma separated list of items.

An object literal `{}` contains a comma separated list of key `:` value pairs.

You have the body of an object literal inside an array literal.

---

Having a trailing comma in array or object literals, while valid in some versions of JS, can be problematic. So remove that too.

---

```
            "data": {
                "date1": $( "#inputDate1" ).val(),
                "date2": $( "#inputDate2" ).val()
            },
```

Comment: Sorry (head is fried :p). My table isn't updated when I hit that button. I don't even see a request sent to the server processing file in the Network tab in Developer Tools.

Comment: Wow, something strange happens (my eyes missed it the first). That server processing file gets added to the Network tab in Developer Tools and the HTML table is populated, but straight after it disappears from the table in the Network tab in Developer Tools and the HTML table is cleared. This all happens in like 0.5 seconds or something.

Comment: @Jack — Whatever you've bound your click event to is probably triggering a new page load (e.g. it is a link or submit button) as well as running the JS.

Comment: Hmm, `<button class="btn btn-default" id="button1">Update</button>`?

Comment: That's a submit button, if its in a form, it will submit the form.

Comment: There is no `type="submit"` though? It's just a button, no?

Comment: `submit` is the default value for `type` for a `button` element

Answer (score 2):

You had one comma that does not belong there. As stated below, another problem is that arrays cannot have associative keys .

```
<script>
$( "#button1" ).click(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
                "data": {
                    "date1": $( "#inputDate1" ).val(),
                    "date2": $( "#inputDate2" ).val() // No , here
                },
                "url": "/server_processing/database.php",
                "type": "POST"
                },
        "serverSide": true
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Another problem is that arrays cannot have associative keys

Comment: Thanks. totally missed that :) Edited my answer.